# How to redirect stdout to a COM Port

Tags: c, windows, serial-port, stdout

Could anyone tell me how to redirect stdout to a COM port in C?

Working on a Windows machine.  Reading online Microsoft use device files and device keywords, like CON for console. They have some for COM Ports too, 'COM1'.

However, doing this didnt seem to work? >> `freopen( "COM5", "w", stdout );`

Thank you for your help.

cjg199

Comment: What didn't work about it?

Comment: ran a print f statement after changing it, and it didnt appear?

Comment: Did it return an error?

Comment: The code is running on a, development kit, and im using puTTy over the COM5 Port, to provide inputs and read outputs.

There is a series of print functions with the toolset, but they wont print a float, which is what i need. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A COMx is a serial device and has to be configured. Under the hood, putty (or kermit or hyperterminal) do configure baudrate, size, parity and stop bits.

And a COM device should be opened with exclusive access. It means that if a putty already controls the line, you will not be able to open it in another program.

So the normal usage is:

- open the device (`CreateFile` WinAPI function)
- configure the device (`GetCommState` - `SetCommState`)
- get a file descriptor for the windows handle (`_open_osfhandle`)
- duplicate the file descriptor to fd 1 with `dup2`

After that, you should be able to write to stdout of to fd 1 and get the output on the serial line.

Limited code (no error processing and untested because I currently have no serial device):

```
HANDLE hCom;
DCB dcb;
BOOL fSuccess;
int fd, cr;
hCom = CreateFile( TEXT("COM5"), GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
    0,    // exclusive access 
    NULL, // default security attributes 
    OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);

// Build on the current configuration, and skip setting the size
// of the input and output buffers with SetupComm.

SecureZeroMemory(&dcb, sizeof(DCB));
dcb.DCBlength = sizeof(DCB);
fSuccess = GetCommState(hCom, &dcb);

// Fill in DCB: 57,600 bps, 8 data bits, no parity, and 1 stop bit - adapt to YOUR config

dcb.BaudRate = CBR_57600;     // set the baud rate
dcb.ByteSize = 8;             // data size, xmit, and rcv
dcb.Parity = NOPARITY;        // no parity bit
dcb.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;    // one stop bit

fSuccess = SetCommState(hCom, &dcb);

fd = _open_osfhandle(hCom, 0);
cr = _dup2(fd, 1);
```

References :

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363201%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bdts1c9x%28v=vs.71%29.aspx